# Camera board and reflective strip

Tags: camera

Trying to use the Raspberry Pi camera board to capture an image when it "sees" a reflective strip. Is this possible? How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange! This question has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi, probably another computer-vision related area would get you more answers.

Answer (score 1):

I will at least answer the RasPi part of your question.

Here is how to get images from the camera module into OpenCV: http://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencv-and-camera-board-csi/

Be aware that you will be lucky to get above 5 FPS with this method, but it is probably as  good as it will get with this method.

As for the CV part, you are asking in the wrong place.

Comment: What CV part are you referring to?

Comment: Computer Vision - you would need some kind of computer vision algorithm to detect the "reflective strip".